# WP8 how to interact with controls in other screens

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

how can I interact with controls/objects, i.e. changing a property or firing a method, which are located in another screen/class using C# for Windows Phone 8?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this as an answer I don't have enough reputation for this. What you can do is use the PhoneApplicationService.State that is a dictionnary where you can store any object. The data remains here until you leave the application.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of the dictionary